# how to search data from data base with multiselect or text box in php

Tags: php, mysql

when an user search by category then data is display if an user want to search by mobile then data is display.

user can search any record by category or by status or mobile.

here is the code whatever i have tried.

```
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $status = $_POST['status'];
  $priority = $_POST['priority'];
   $ticket = $_POST['ticket'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
      echo $mobile;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ticketreg WHERE 1";
    if(isset($status) && $status != '') {
   $query .= " And status Like'%$status%'";
   }
    if(isset($priority) && $priority != '') {
   $query .= " OR priority Like'%$priority%'";
    }
   if(isset($ticket) && $ticket != '') {
   $query .= " OR ticket Like '%$ticket%'";
  }
   if(isset($mobile) && $mobile != '') {
  $query .= " OR EMAILID Like '%$mobile%'";
 }




$result = mysql_query($query); 


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {



 ?>
```

please give me some hint for this. here the html code.

```
   <form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="searchresult.php">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" >
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="singup-text">Date : </td><td width="5"></td>
    <td> <span style="font-size:12px; margin-right:3px;">From </span><input id="date"            name="date" class="postsellbox1" style="width:75px; " type="text">
  <span style="font-size:12px; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px;">to </span> <input    id="date"  name="date" class="postsellbox1" style="width:75px; " type="text"> 

   </td>
     <td class="singup-text" >Status : </td><td width="5"></td>
     <td><select id="StatusDropDown" name="status" class="postsellbox"    style="width:130px;" >

           <option value="101">--Select--</option>
          <option value="search">pending</option>
          <option value="search">Assigned</option>
        <option value="search">Cancelled</option>
        <option value="104">Closed</option>

        </select></td>
        <td class="singup-text" >Priority : </td><td width="5"></td>
          <td><select id="PriorityDropDown" name="priority" class="postsellbox" style="width:130px;" >

           <option value="101">--Select--</option>
          <option value="101">High</option>
          <option value="102">Medium</option>
          <option value="103">Normal</option>


        </select></td></tr>
      <tr><td height="15"></td></tr>
      <tr><td class="singup-text" >Category : </td><td width="5"></td>
         <td><select id="CategoryDropDown" name="category" class="postsellbox" style="width:130px;" >

           <option value="100">--Select--</option>
        <option value="101">Electricity</option>
        <option value="102">Painting</option>
        <option value="103">Plumbing</option>
        <option value="104">Carpentry</option>

      </select></td>
      <td class="singup-text">Ticket : </td><td width="5"></td>
        <td><input id="ticket no."  name="ticket" class="postsellbox1" style="width:130px;" type="text" value=""></td>
          <td class="singup-text">Mobile : </td><td width="5"></td>
             <td><input id="Mobile"  name="mobile" class="postsellbox1" style="width:130px;" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>

            <td><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Search" ></td>
           </tr>
                <tr>

         <td><input class="submit1" type="reset" value="Reset" ></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
             </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ticketreg WHERE 1";
    if(isset($status) && $status != '') {
   $query .= " And status Like'%$status%'";
   }
    if(isset($priority) && $priority != '') {
   $query .= " OR priority Like'%$priority%'";
    }
   if(isset($ticket) && $ticket != '') {
   $query .= " OR ticket Like '%$ticket%'";
  }
   if(isset($mobile) && $mobile != '') {
  $query .= " OR EMAILID Like '%$mobile%'";
 }
```

Edit:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM ticketreg WHERE ";
    if(isset($status) && $status != '') {
   $query .= "status Like'%$status%' OR";
   }
    if(isset($priority) && $priority != '') {
   $query .= " priority Like'%$priority%' OR ";
    }
   if(isset($ticket) && $ticket != '') {
   $query .= " ticket Like '%$ticket%' OR ";
  }
   if(isset($mobile) && $mobile != '') {
  $query .= " EMAILID Like '%$mobile%' OR ";
 }
 $query = substr($query,0,-3);
```